# Massive White Space at Bottom of Wordpress Front Page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, whitespace

The front page of my Wordpress blog contains a content area with posts sorted into three columns using CSS columns. Below it is a footer, see "The end." Below that is a massive amount of white space that I can't figure out. When I inspect it, it doesn't appear as part of any element, but the html tag is highlighted.

See it here: http://www.kailepley.org

This happens on latest Chrome and Safari, other browsers unknown so far.

I've searched around a tried quite a few different fixes, but nothing has worked so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Happens on which browsers? Did you enable any plugins recently that might have caused this issue?

Comment: Note, I can see the white space in Chrome, but not in Firefox

Comment: Chrome and Safari - thanks. I don't think I have any plugins enabled, and certainly no new ones.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: When I remove -webkit-column-count: 3; from .page-home, your entries appear in a single column, and all the white space disappears. So that seems to be what's causing it - hope that points you in the right direction...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an element:

```
<span class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</span>
```

with the CSS:

```
.screen-reader-text {
clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
position: absolute !important;
height: 1px;
width: 1px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

and the culprit is the line `position: absolute !important;`

Comment: Thanks j08691! I simply added top: 0; to the .screen-reader-text class and it fixed the problem.